# Whats the difference between ? : and ||

Tags: php

What difference is there between using the `?:` conditional operator and the `||` Logical `OR`.

I am finding that my code works with:

```
$screenpixelratio = !empty($_COOKIE['screenpixelratio']) || $_COOKIE['screenpixelratio'] || $fallback_pixelratio;
```

But not:

```
$screenpixelratio = !empty($_COOKIE['screenpixelratio']) ? $_COOKIE['screenpixelratio'] : $fallback_pixelratio;
```

Could someone please explain why it would work with one, but not the other.

Comment: One (called the ternary operator) is the equivalent of a simplified "if test"; the other is a logical "or" - pretty major difference, doing totally different things

Comment: The second example is a ternary operator. The first one assigns the first truthy value it encounters to `$screenpixelration`.

Comment: I'm gonna be "that guy" :). `?:` is *a* ternary operator, not *the* ternary operator (ternary operator is a category of operators). It's specific name is the conditional operator. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operator is the category. Look under "See also" on that page for the conditional operator (the link doesn't work because of the `:` in the URL).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`||` Binary operators are operators that deal with two arguments

as its says it will check first if its true than not gonna check further else check further

`?:` ternary operator is an operator that takes three arguments. The arguments and result can be of different types.

```
Expression1 ? Expression2 : Expression3;
```

[image]

Answer (score 18):

The first ([conditional or](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php)) is saying...

```
this or this or this
```

The other ([ternary operation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary)) is saying

```
if this then this otherwise that
```